# exif_imagetype(data:): failed to open stream: rfc2397

Tags: php

здравствуйте, перед раскодировкой bese64decode изображения, и сохранение его на сервер (file put content), стоит элементарная проверка:

if (!exif_imagetype($avatar)) exit();

меня все устраивает, функция просто перестает выполнять работу скрипта, если человек попробовал загрузить любые файлы кроме картинок. Но есть 1 минус, если попытаться загрузить пустой .txt файл то пользователю выбьет ошибку

Warning: exif_imagetype(data:): failed to open stream: rfc2397: no comma in URL in (ссылка на скрипт проверки)

технически все в порядке, скрипт просто отказался принимать странный файл, но ошибка не должна выводится, как можно её скрыть?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать проверку длины файла перед запуском *exif_imagetype()* таким образом

```
if (filesize($avatar) < 12 || !exif_imagetype($avatar)) exit();
```

По мотивам http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exif-imagetype.php#79283